# Prometheus can not scrape kong-ingress-controller metrics

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus-operator, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I've installed **Prometheus** and **Grafana** to monitor my **K8S cluster** and **microservices** using **helm charts**:

```
helm install monitoring prometheus-community/kube-promehteus-stack --values prometheus-values.yaml --version 16.10.0 --namespace monitoring --create-namespace
```

the content of `promehteus-values.yaml` is:

```
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    serviceMonitorSelector:
      matchLabels:
        prometheus: devops
commonLabels:
  prometheus: devops
grafana:
  adminPassword: test123
```

Then I installed `kong-ingress-controller` using `helm-charts`:

```
helm install kong kong/kong --namespace kong --create-namespace --values kong.yaml --set ingressController.installCRDs=false
```

the content of `kong.yaml` file is:

```
podAnnotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    prometheus.io/port: "8100"
```

I've also changed the value of `metricsBindAdress` in `kube-proxy` **configmap** to `0.0.0.0:10249` .

then I installed `kong prometheus plugin` using this `yaml file` :

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongClusterPlugin
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
  labels:
    global: "true"
plugin: prometheus
```

My `kong endpoint` is :

`$ kubectl edit endpoints -n kong kong-kong-proxy`

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  annotations:
    endpoints.kubernetes.io/last-change-trigger-time: "2021-10-27T03:28:25Z"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-10-26T04:44:57Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kong
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kong
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.6"
    enable-metrics: "true"
    helm.sh/chart: kong-2.5.0
  name: kong-kong-proxy
  namespace: kong
  resourceVersion: "6553623"
  uid: 91f2054f-7fb9-4d63-8b65-be098b8f6547
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 10.233.96.41
    nodeName: node2
    targetRef:
      kind: Pod
      name: kong-kong-69fd7d7698-jjkj5
      namespace: kong
      resourceVersion: "6510442"
      uid: 26c6bdca-e9f1-4b32-91ff-0fadb6fce529
  ports:
  - name: kong-proxy
    port: 8000
    protocol: TCP
  - name: kong-proxy-tls
    port: 8443
    protocol: TCP
```

Finally I wrote the `serviceMonitor` for `kong` like this :

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  generation: 1
  labels:
    prometheus: devops
  name: kong-sm
  namespace: kong
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 30s
    port: kong-proxy
    scrapeTimeout: 10s
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - kong
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: kong
```

After all of this ; the `targets` in `prometheus dashboard` looks like this:

[image]

What did I miss/do wrong?

Comment: did u find the solution ?

Comment: @newcomers not yet

Comment: I don't know if it would be the same. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdgBo2dPst8

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look to the **Kong deployment** first **(** pay extra attention to the bottom of this file **)**:

`kubectl edit deploy -n kong kong-kong` :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    [...]
  creationTimestamp: "2021-10-26T04:44:58Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: app
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kong
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kong
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.6"
    helm.sh/chart: kong-2.5.0
  name: kong-kong
  namespace: kong
  [...]
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: app
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: kong
      app.kubernetes.io/name: kong
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    [...]
   - env:
        [...]
        image: kong:2.6
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        [...]
        name: proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          name: proxy
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: proxy-tls
          protocol: TCP
         ############################################
         ## THIS PART IS IMPORTANT TO US :          #
         ############################################
        - containerPort: 8100 
          name: status
          protocol: TCP
        [...]
```

As you can see, in the `sepc.template.spec.env.ports` part we have **3 ports**, the **8100** will be used for get **metrics** so if you can't see this port in the **kong endpoint**, add it manually to the bottom of kong endpoint:

`$ kubectl edit endpoints -n kong kong-kong-proxy` :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  annotations:
    endpoints.kubernetes.io/last-change-trigger-time: "2021-10-26T04:44:58Z"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-10-26T04:44:57Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kong
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kong
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.6"
    enable-metrics: "true"
    helm.sh/chart: kong-2.5.0
  name: kong-kong-proxy
  namespace: kong
  resourceVersion: "7160332"
  uid: 91f2054f-7fb9-4d63-8b65-be098b8f6547
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 10.233.96.41
    nodeName: node2
    targetRef:
      kind: Pod
      name: kong-kong-69fd7d7698-jjkj5
      namespace: kong
      resourceVersion: "6816178"
      uid: 26c6bdca-e9f1-4b32-91ff-0fadb6fce529
  ports:
  - name: kong-proxy
    port: 8000
    protocol: TCP
  - name: kong-proxy-tls
    port: 8443
    protocol: TCP
#######################################
##        ADD THE 8100 PORT HERE      #
#######################################
  - name: kong-status
    port: 8100
    protocol: TCP
```

Then save this file and change the **serviceMonitor** of **kong** like this **(** the **port** name is the **same** to the **endpoint** we added recently **)**:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  generation: 1
  labels:
    prometheus: devops
  name: kong-sm
  namespace: kong
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 30s
#############################################################################
##   THE NAME OF THE PORT IS SAME TO THE NAME WE ADDED TO THE ENDPOINT FILE #
#############################################################################
    port: kong-status
    scrapeTimeout: 10s
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - kong
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: kong
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
      app.kubernetes.io/name: kong
      app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.6"
      enable-metrics: "true"
      helm.sh/chart: kong-2.5.0
```

Apply the **serviceMonitor** yaml file and after few seconds **Prometheus** will detect it as a **target** and scrape kong's metrics successfully.